# Solutions to $\binom{n}{5} = 2 \binom{m}{5}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, diophantine-equations, co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory

In *Finite Mathematics* by Lial et al. (10th ed.), problem 8.3.34 says:

> On National Public Radio, the *Weekend Edition* program posed the
>   following probability problem: Given a certain number of balls, of
>   which some are blue, pick 5 at random.  The probability that all 5 are
>   blue is 1/2.  Determine the original number of balls and decide how
>   many were blue.

If there are $n$ balls, of which $m$ are blue, then the probability that 5 randomly chosen balls are all blue is $\binom{m}{5} / \binom{n}{5}$.  We want this to be $1/2$,
so $\binom{n}{5} = 2\binom{m}{5}$; equivalently,
$n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4) = 2 m(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)(m-4)$.
I'll denote these quantities as $[n]_5$ and $2 [m]_5$ (this is a notation for the so-called "falling factorial.")

A little fooling around will show that $[m+1]_5 = \frac{m+1}{m-4}[m]_5$.
Solving $\frac{m+1}{m-4} = 2$ shows that the only solution with $n = m + 1$ has $m = 9$, $n = 10$.

**Is this the only solution?**

You can check that $n = m + 2$ doesn't yield any integer solutions, by using the quadratic formula to solve $(m + 2)(m  +1) = 2(m - 3)(m - 4)$.  For $n = m + 3$ or $n = m + 4$, I have done similar checks, and there are no integer solutions.  For $n \geq m + 5$, solutions would satisfy a quintic equation, which of course has no general formula to find solutions.

Note that, as $n$ gets bigger, the ratio of successive values of $\binom{n}{5}$ gets smaller; $\binom{n+1}{5} = \frac{n+1}{n-4}\binom{n}{5}$
and $\frac{n+1}{n-4}$ is less than 2—in fact, it approaches 1. So it seems possible that, for some $k$, $\binom{n+k}{5}$ could be $2 \binom{n}{5}$.

This question was [previously asked at Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344427/solutions-to-binomn5-2-binomm5), without any answer, but some interesting comments were made. It was suggested that I ask here.

Comment: The equation defines a smooth quintic so there are only finitely many solutions. 

Comment: Any solutions have $n=\lfloor 2^{1/5} m\rfloor$, so there are no further solutions for $m\le 10,000,000$.

Comment: For what it's worth: I've checked that there are no other solutions for n up to 35 billion or so.

Answer (score 14):

This isn’t a complete answer, but the problem “reduces” to finding the finitely many rational points on a certain genus 2 hyperelliptic curve. This is often possible by a technique
involving a reduction to finding the rational points on a finite set of rank 0 elliptic curves—see for example “Towers of 2-covers of hyperelliptic curves” by Bruin and Flynn in Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 357 (2005) #11 4329–4347.

In your case, the curve is $u^2= 9t^6+16t^5-200t^3+256t+144$. There are the following 16
rational points: $(t,u)$ or $(t,-u)= (0,12)$, $(1,15)$, $(2,12)$, $(4,204)$, $(-1,9)$, $(-2,36)$, $(-4,180)$, and $(7/4,411/64)$. If these are the only rational points then the only non-trivial solution to your equation is $n=10$, $m=9$. To see this suppose that $$n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)=2m(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)(m-4).$$ Let $$y=(n-2)^2\text{ and }x=(m-2)^2.$$ Squaring both sides we find that $$y(y-1)(y-1)(y-4)(y-4)=4x(x-1)(x-1)(x-4)(x-4).$$ Suppose $y$ isn’t $0$. Then $4x/y$ is $t^2$ for some rational $t$ with $$(y-1)(y-4)=t(x-1)(x-4).$$ We replace $y$ by $4x/t^2$ in this equation and find that $$(t^5-16)x^2-(5t^5-20t^2)x+(4t^5-4t^4)=0.$$ So this last quadratic polynomial in $x$ has a rational root and its
discriminant is a square. This gives the hyperelliptic curve above. Note that the case $n=10$, $m=9$ of your problem corresponds to the point $(7/4,411/64)$ on this curve.

**EDIT:**

More generally one can look for rational $m$ and $n$ with $[n]_5= 2[m]_5$. If $(t,u)$ is a
rational point on the hyperelliptic curve with $t$ non-zero, set $x=(5t^5-20t^2+t^2u)/(2t^5-32)$ and $y=4x/t^2$. Then if $x$ is a square in $\mathbb Q$, one gets such an $m$ and $n$ with $m=2+\sqrt x$ and $n=2+\sqrt y$. Joro’s points lead in this way to the solutions
$(n,m)=(10,9)$, $(10/3,5/3)$, and $(78/23,36/23)$, the last one being rather unexpected. (And as François notes, each $(n,m)$ gives a second solution $(4-n,4-m)$.) Perhaps these solutions and
the trivial solutions with $m$ and $n \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ are the only rational solutions.

Comment: Looks like there are more points on the curve. $t$ are:  [-4, -13/5, -2, -1, -5/8, -1/2, -8/27, 0, 26/41, 1, 7/4, 2, 36/17, 4]

Comment: According to Magma the Jacobian $J$ of this hyperelliptic curve has rank 4 and satisfies End(J)=Z over the complex numbers ; in particular this genus 2 curve has no elliptic quotient.

Comment: The curve C defined by $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ 5\end{pmatrix} =2 \begin{pmatrix}m \\ 5\end{pmatrix}$ has genus 6. I guess the genus 2 curve in your answer is the quotient of C by the involution $(m,n) \to (4−m,4−n)$, which is the only obvious automorphism.

Comment: Using Stahlke and Stoll's program **ratpoints**,
I find that there are no further rational solutions of
$u^2 = 9t^6+16t^5-200t^3+256t+144$ with $u=r/s$ and
$|r|,|s| \leq 10^5$.
On the original equation, it should be easy to show there
are no further solutions up to say $10^{100}$ using the fact that
$(n-2)/(m-2) = 2^{1/5} + O(1/m)$, so there are only a few hundred
approximations to $2^{1/5}$ that are close enough, and they can be
computed via the continued-fraction expansion.
