# Integer solutions of Diophantine equation $y^2= 1+4n^{\underline k} $

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory

I am looking for the integer solutions for the diophantine equation $y^2 =4n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)+1$ for a given $k$ where $n>k+1>5$.

In other words,
$$y^2=1+4n^{\underline k},\tag{I}$$
where $n^{\underline k} =n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

**Source of the problem:**

The main problem is: Solve the equation $$\frac{m!}{(m-2)!}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

$m(m-1)$ must be equal to $n^{\underline k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

So we must solve the equation

$$m^2-m -n^{\underline k}=0$$ which has integer solution only if $1+4n^{\underline k}$ is a perfect square, where $n^{\underline k} =n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot (n-k+1)$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

**Known facts:**

1. $n^{\underline k}$ is not a power (see [The Product of consecutive integers is never a power by P. Erdos s and J. L. Selfridge](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256050816)), so $4n^{\underline k}$ is not a square.
2. We know,  quadratic-residue $\times$ quadratic-nonresidue = quadratic-nonresidue.
3. Steven Stadnicki suggested that there is a link between the problem and [Singmaster's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster%27s_conjecture), though I don't understand it.
4. For $k=3$, $E_k (F)$ is an elliptic curve and thus the equation $(I)$ has finite solutions, to be specific $1$. In an elementary way, it can be shown, equation $(I)$ has no solution, since $4P(n,k)+1=(2n^2-6n+2)^2-3$ is a square for finite cases..
5. See the article of [Bugeaud, Y.; Mignotte, M.; Siksek, S.; Stoll, M.; Tengely, Sz.: Integral points
   on hyperelliptic curves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.4459.pdf). They succesfully treat the equation
   $$
   n(n+1)=\frac{m!}{60(m-5)!}
   $$
   In fact, it follows that $m\in \lbrace{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15, 19\rbrace}$, there is
   hope for equations of type $\binom{n}{\ell}=\binom{m}{k}$.
6. For any $k$ there are finitely many solutions by Siegel's theorem (and for $k>4$ there are finitely many rational solutions by Faltings).

**Algebraic geometry:**

Let us define a curve $E_k (F):=y^2 =4n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)+1$ for a given $k$ when $F=\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$.  In other words, $E_k (F):=y^2=  1+4n^{\underline k}$.

**Question**:

1. Is there infinite integer solutions to the equation $(I)$?
2. Provided the answer to the question is yes, then, what are the integer solutions of the equation $(I)$?

Please consider non-trivial cases.

**If above questions are too difficult to answer please, advise how to approach to this problem and *what else are known*. Also let me know the computational approach in this problem.**

**EDIT:**

One may find relation to Brocard's problem or $abc$ conjecture, but please note that you are refereeing to the problems which are more general in nature, on the other hand, my problem is more specific.

Comment: For any $k$ there are finitely many solutions by Siegel's theorem (and for $k>4$ there are finitely many *rational* solutions by Faltings). Whether there are infinitely many solutions across all $k$ is most certainly a completely intractable problem, similar to the famous [Brocard's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem). I suspect the answer is no, but have no idea how one could prove it.

Comment: Also see this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128036/solutions-to-binomn5-2-binomm5

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you for your valuable feedback, but I can not see the connection between Brocard's problem and the problem I posted, could you comment on that plz?

Comment: Remove the $4$ and let $k=n$, then you get Brocard. I'm not saying one problem would follow from the other, I'm just saying they look similar and that makes me believe they are similarly hopeless.

Comment: For a fixed value of $n-k$, finiteness of solutions follows from the abc conjecture by the result of Luca mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem#Variants_of_the_problem)

Comment: @Wojowu you are refereeing to the problems which are more general in nature, on the other hand, my problem is more specific, see the article of Bugeaud, Y.; Mignotte, M.; Siksek, S.; Stoll, M.; Tengely, Sz.: Integral points on hyperelliptic curves,  there is better hope for equations of type$ \binom{n}{\ell}=\binom{m}{k}$.